# How to open a ZIP using remote url?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to open a ZIP file by passing a remote URL (`http://www.example.com/file.zip` or `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/file.zip`) instead of a file location (`C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\uploads\file.zip`)

This constructor works fine for a file location but not for a remote `url` of a file. How does one open a file using a remote URL for this scenario?

```
public function __construct($file = false)
{
    if ($file && is_file($file)) {
    //$file="C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\uploads\file.zip" here
        $this->open($file);
        $this->fileName = basename($this->filePath = $file);
    } else {
        throw new \Exception($file . " not a regular file");
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read Zip file from URL with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310407/read-zip-file-from-url-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is to

1. download the file
   This is super easy if `allow_url_fopen` is enabled: `file_get_contents()` accepts remote URLs. If that's not enabled, use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) or a Wordpress HTTP helper to download it.
2. save it locally
   Also super easy, with `file_put_contents()`. The `/tmp` folder is probably writable for you. On Windows, I don't know where the tmp folder lives.
3. open it like any other
   As you would a local ZIP archive, with `ZipArchive::open()` or your nameless class

Comment: Thanks for Reply @Rudie . Can I use `ini_get('upload_tmp_dir')` instead of local /tmp ?
I've slow internet connection so I would like if there is no need to save it locally when zip files are large.

Comment: You can use any dir you have write access to. You have to download it, any way you aproach this. Saving it locally or not. The only way to not download the whole thing, is to stream it, and read the archive index first, but I don't think ZipArchive supports that. Maybe you can find a "php streaming zip archive" lib..?

Comment: Nope, you can't stream/selectively download a remote ZIP file over HTTP. `stream_copy_to_stream()` might be interesting though.

Answer (score 0):

just use php fopen function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

```
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "r");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this to get the contents of a webpage but not a zip file - not sure if that will work but it did well for me. `$contents` definitely worked for text.

```
    // For PHP 5 and up
    $handle = fopen("https://www.thesiteyouwant.com/the_target_file.ext", "r");
    $contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php